# Disable input field when click edit button using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in here.
The scenario is that I am on the user profile details and I want to edit the information but one input must be disable at all the time.
When I'm loading the page the input it is actually disabled but as soon as I click the edit button it is becoming editable like the rest of the other input.
Any suggestion on how to make it works, please?

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

const handleClickEditMember = () => {
  Actions.enableMemberEdit();
  setDisabled(!disabled);
};

<Card className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
  <CardHeader
    action={
      <Button
        color="primary"
        id="edit-member-button"
        onClick={() => handleClickEditMember()}
        size="small"
        variant="contained"
      >
        {t('members.edit')}
      </Button>
    }
    title={member.companyName}
  />
  <Divider />
  <CardContent className={classes.content}>
    <CardHeader title={t('members.company_profile')} />
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField
          className={classes.textField}
          fullWidth
          id="companyName"
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: true,
          }}
          label={t('members.company_name')}
          margin="dense"
          name="companyName"
          placeholder={t('members.company_name')}
          value={member.companyName}
          variant="outlined"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <TextField
          className={classes.textField}
          fullWidth
          id="Id"
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: true,
          }}
          disabled={!disabled}
          label={t('members.id')}
          margin="dense"
          name="Id"
          placeholder={t('members.id')}
          value={member.id}
          variant="outlined"
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved by doing this:

```
InputProps={{
  readOnly: memberId ? true : false,
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField
    className={classes.textField}
    fullWidth
    id="Id"
    InputProps={{
        readOnly: true,
    }}
    **disabled**
    label={t('members.id')}
    margin="dense"
    name="Id"
    placeholder={t('members.id')}
    value={member.id}
    variant="outlined"
/>
```

Just disable the textfield. Don't assign any value to disabled property

Comment: I did try to use only disable but for some reason it gets editable everytime I'm click on edit button

Comment: try removing this  InputProps={{ readOnly: true, }}

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the state everytime in the `handleClickEditMember()` by doing `setDisabled(!disabled);` which will eventually set to true as its false initially.

So you'll have to

- Remove that piece of code and the state update won't be triggered again!
- And For the ID input field just use `disabled={disabled}`

Comment: I did try to use only disable but for some reason it gets editable everytime I'm click on edit button